Any mention about indus vally Civilization in Indian ancient text?
Which kind of mention we find in indian text about indus vally civilization. 100 years of Civilization finding where we stand.
Connected or linked question where the timeline of Central Asia Aryan Invasion theory.

I am vote to close this question as it lacks focus and facts and details and a relation to a timeline.
